# How to split a string in python including whitespace?

Tags: python, split

Final result should look like this:

```
string = "this is a simple text"
result = ["this", " ", "is", " ", "a", " ", "simple", " ", "text"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to split with a regex and capture the delimiter:

```
import re

string = "this is a simple text"

re.split(r'(\s+)', string)
# ['this', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'simple', ' ', 'text']
```

Note, this will act a little different than `str.split()` on an empty string.